# convert python's time.ctime() to unix time stamp

Tags: python, numpy, time, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert the current time ('Wed Sep  6 15:31:35 2017') that returns Python3.5 to Unix time stamp.

```
time.ctime.astype(np.int64)
```

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'astype'

when I try

```
np.int64(time.ctime())
```

I get:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Wed Sep  6 15:34:08 2017'

Comment: Why not [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time)? `time.ctime()` returns a string.

Comment: thanks, it worked with int(time.time())

Comment: Also note that your first error is attempting to cast a function, `time.ctime`, and not the return of the function, `time.ctime()`. It's still going to error out, but it's important to recognize the difference in returns between the two syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`time.ctime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.ctime) returns a *string* representation of the current time, as returned (in seconds since the epoch) by `time.time()`.

You can cut out the middleman and use [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) on its own, which returns a floating point representation of the seconds:

```
t = int(time.time())
```

Answer (score 2):

`time.ctime()` returns a string representation of the time

use `strptime` from module `datetime` to parse string to a datetime object

```
import datetime
import time
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print(t.timestamp()) #1504730409.0
```

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

You can do it more easily this way:

```
import time
math.floor(time.time())
```